# Continuous synthesis of static waveform in Android using AudioTrack class

Tags: android, audio, audiotrack

Below is the code for my `play()` method which simply generates an arbitrary set of  frequencies and blends them into one tone.

The problem is that it only plays for a split second - I need is to play it continuously. I would appreciate suggestions on how to constantly generate the sound using the AudioTrack class in Android. I believe it has something to do with the `MODE_STREAM` constant, but I can't quite work out how.

Here is the link to AudioTrack class documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html

EDIT: I forgot to mention one important aspect, it can't loop. Due to the mixing of sometimes up to 50+ frequencies, it will sound choppy because there is no least common denominator for all frequency peaks - or it's too far down the waveform to store as one sound.

```
/**
 * play - begins playing the sound
 */
public void play() {
    // Get array of frequencies with their relative strengths
    double[][] soundData = getData();

    // Track samples array
    final double samples[] = new double[1024];

    // Calculate the average sum in the array and write it to sample
    for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; ++i) {
            double valueSum = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < soundData.length; j++) {
                valueSum += Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (SAMPLE_RATE / soundData[j][0]));
            }

            samples[i] = valueSum / soundData.length;
    }

    // Obtain a minimum buffer size
    int minBuffer = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    if (minBuffer > 0) {

        // Create an AudioTrack
        mTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, 
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBuffer, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        // Begin playing track
        mTrack.play();

        // Fill the buffer
        if (mBuffer.length < samples.length) {
             mBuffer = new short[samples.length];
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < samples.length; k++) {
            mBuffer[k] = (short) (samples[k] * Short.MAX_VALUE);
        }

        // Write audio data to track for real-time audio sythesis
        mTrack.write(mBuffer, 0, samples.length);

    }

    // Once everything has successfully begun, indicate such.
    isPlaying = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code is almost there. It just needs a loop to keep generating the samples, putting them in the buffer, and writing them to the AudioTrack. Right now just one buffer full gets written before it exits which is why it stops so quickly.

```
void getSamples(double[] samples) {
    // Get array of frequencies with their relative strengths
    double[][] soundData = getData();

    // Calculate the average sum in the array and write it to sample
    for (int i = 0; i < samples.length; ++i) {
            double valueSum = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < soundData.length; j++) {
                valueSum += Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (SAMPLE_RATE / soundData[j][0]));
            }

            samples[i] = valueSum / soundData.length;
    }
}

public void endPlay() {
    done = true;
}

/**
 * play - begins playing the sound
 */
public void play() {
    // Obtain a minimum buffer size
    int minBuffer = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

    if (minBuffer > 0) {

        // Create an AudioTrack
        mTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, 
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBuffer, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        // Begin playing track
        mTrack.play();

        // Track samples array
        final double samples[] = new double[1024];

        while (!done) {
            // Fill the buffer
            if (mBuffer.length < samples.length) {
                 mBuffer = new short[samples.length];
            }

            getSamples(samples);

            for (int k = 0; k < samples.length; k++) {
                mBuffer[k] = (short) (samples[k] * Short.MAX_VALUE);
            }

            // Write audio data to track for real-time audio sythesis
            mTrack.write(mBuffer, 0, samples.length);

            // Once everything has successfully begun, indicate such.
            isPlaying = true;
        }
    }

    // Once everything is done, indicate such.
    isPlaying = false;
}
```